# Undeclared identifier error in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

This is my ViewController.m file's code for Collection view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     img = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png", nil];
     name = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Flag",@"Blue",@"Fish", nil];
     [self.collectionview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [img count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [collectionview dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *reciveimageview = (UIImageView *)[cell1 viewWithTag:100];
    reciveimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell1.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell1.cellLabel.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell1;
}

@end
```

Now it is giving me the error of `Undeclared identifier of Cell and Cell1` 
Don't know why.

Comment: First register your cell with a reusable identifier to the collectionView. Only then you'll be able to de queue the cell with any specific identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add like this
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *recipeImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[jsonImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
```

Comment: It worked, thanks :) But how to show cell's label on a cell?

Comment: I used  cell1.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but didn't work

Comment: UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, cell.bounds.size.width, 40)];
   
     [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cell on the .xib file know what's the type of the cell.

Select the cell on your interface builder

[image]

and then on the identity inspector. In your case it should be `cell`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the identifier in xib as "CELL"

[image]

You need to register your nib/class if you are using a custom cell.
You can do that by

```
[self.myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ShubhCalendarCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ShubhCalendarCollectionViewCell"];
```

Make sure your Nib name and identifier are not mis- spelled.
Hope it helps.

Happyy coding.. !!